# How to have a buffer takes 1/4 of a window and another takes all the rest?

Tags: vimrc, gvim, vim-windows

I have two buffers, and would like one takes 1/4 of a window and other takes rest of the window.

Normal behavior would be for example `sp` or `vsp` would split buffer to take 50/50 percent each, there would be some buffers more important than others so that I raise this question.

In my case, I'd like to have a terminal buffer that takes 1/4 of a window and other takes the rest.

I used gvim 1-1802 on windows 10.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `&columns` setting and some math to achieve this. Do you want to resize your existing splits, or make a new split at the right ratios? Since it's not entirely clear from your question, here's how you can do it both ways.

#### Resizing existing splits

I used this:

```
function! Quarter()
  exec "vertical resize ".(&columns / 4). " N"
endfunction
```

This will resize the existing buffer to a quarter of the screen size. Of course, you can map this to a key, for example:

```
nnoremap <leader>q :call Quarter()<cr>
```

or

```
nnoremap <leader>q :exec "vertical resize ".(&columns / 4). " N"<cr>
```

Or you can bind this function to the `VimResized` event.

#### Making new splits

You can do this:

```
:exec (&columns / 4)." vsplit"
```

to make the current window 1/4 and the new window fill up the rest, or

```
:exec (&columns / 4 * 3)." vsplit"
```

to make the new window 1/4 and the current window fill up the rest.

Comment: Thanks. But how to have both columns and rows take 1/4 of a window? Append `.(&rows / 4)` seems doesn't work. I'd like to have look into both ways new and existing buffer.

Comment: @TuyenPham If you're asking for how to get one window in one corner that is both half the width and half the height of the screen, with a single L-shaped window taking up the other three quarters of the area, that's not possible in Vim.

Comment: @Rich: Is there a way to call new terminal buffer that takes 1/4 of a window base on `rows` in a `new` `split` buffer? I can't find `:h rows` in doc, so maybe there's no `rows` option. For example: `:exec (&rows / 4 * 3)." vsplit :terminal"`

Comment: @TuyenPham The option is called `'lines'`.

Comment: @Rich: I'm trying to invoke new `term` via this command: `nnoremap <c-w>l :exec terminal (&lines / 4 * 3)." vsplit"` but it seems doesn't work, Did I miss something here?